# AWS Quicksight Sheet Relative Filter not considering users Timezone

Tags: amazon-quicksight

We are based in Australia, so UTC+10. When using a filter in the sheet with relative date, it looks like its mapping against the UTC start of day/end of day. Is there a way to setup the user's timezone?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17AQI.png)

Use relative date filter (This day), but it is selecting Yesterday.